# Custom login method appears to ignore auth_cookie_expiration

Tags: login, cookies

I have a custom login form that I can display by adding `[custom-login-form]` to a static page. While the form does look rather different, it still submits its data via method="post" to `wp_login_url()` (with no parameters), as the default login form does.

I send users to the page via a plugin, like this:

```
add_action( 'login_form_login', array( $this, 'redirect_to_custom_login' ) ); // login
public function redirect_to_custom_login() {
    if ( 'GET' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        if ( '' !== $this->redirect_after_login_url ) {
            $redirect_to = $this->redirect_after_login_url;
        } else {
            $redirect_to = null;
        }
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $this->redirect_logged_in_user( $redirect_to );
            exit;
        }

        // The rest are redirected to the login page
        $login_url = site_url( 'user/login' );
        if ( ! empty( $redirect_to ) ) {
            $login_url = add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', $redirect_to, $login_url );
        }

        wp_redirect( $login_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I try to send non-admin users back to the page they were on after logging in, as well:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', array( $this, 'redirect_after_login' ), 10, 3 ); // login
public function redirect_after_login( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user ) {
    $redirect_url = site_url();

    if ( ! isset( $user->ID ) ) {
        return $redirect_url;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $user->roles[0] ) && in_array( $user->roles[0], array( 'administrator' ) ) ) {
        // Use the redirect_to parameter if one is set, otherwise redirect to admin dashboard.
        if ( '' === $requested_redirect_to ) {
            $redirect_url = admin_url();
        } else {
            $redirect_url = $requested_redirect_to;
        }
    } else {
        // Non-admin users go to their account page after login, unless another url is supplied
        if ( '' === $requested_redirect_to ) {
            $redirect_url = site_url( 'user' );
        } else {
            $redirect_url = $requested_redirect_to;
        }
    }

    return wp_validate_redirect( $redirect_url, site_url() );
}
```

I'm also using the following code to try to keep users from being logged out:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'custom_login_expiration' ) ) :
    add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'custom_login_expiration' );
    function custom_login_expiration( $expirein ) {
        return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
    }
endif;
```

But I'm getting consistent reports from multiple users that they have to keep logging in each day. I haven't had to do this myself, which is probably because I haven't been inactive for long enough. The reporting users are not administrators, but subscribers, contributors, editors, etc.

I can't see any evidence that my custom login hooks should have to set the cookie themselves - they don't seem to intercept that process, as far as I can tell - but I can't see out another reason that users would be logged out independently of the authorization expiration.

Update: I've discovered that admin level users **are** getting the proper cookies set, and thus they are able to stay logged in. But if a user is not sent to an admin page upon login, they do not get `wp-settings-time-{user_id}` and `wp-settings-{user_id}` cookies set.

I've tried a quick version of the `wp_user_settings()` method that Core uses to set these cookies. This does indeed set the expiration value, but it does not keep the user logged in when they close their browser.

```
function my_user_settings() {

    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! $user_id = get_current_user_id() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! is_user_member_of_blog() ) {
        return;
    }

    $settings = (string) get_user_option( 'user-settings', $user_id );

    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['wp-settings-' . $user_id] ) ) {
        $cookie = preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9=&_]/', '', $_COOKIE['wp-settings-' . $user_id] );

        // No change or both empty
        if ( $cookie == $settings )
            return;

        $last_saved = (int) get_user_option( 'user-settings-time', $user_id );
        $current = isset( $_COOKIE['wp-settings-time-' . $user_id]) ? preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $_COOKIE['wp-settings-time-' . $user_id] ) : 0;

        // The cookie is newer than the saved value. Update the user_option and leave the cookie as-is
        if ( $current > $last_saved ) {
            update_user_option( $user_id, 'user-settings', $cookie, false );
            update_user_option( $user_id, 'user-settings-time', time() - 5, false );
            return;
        }
    }

    // The cookie is not set in the current browser or the saved value is newer.
    $secure = ( 'https' === parse_url( site_url(), PHP_URL_SCHEME ) );
    setcookie( 'wp-settings-' . $user_id, $settings, time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, null, $secure );
    setcookie( 'wp-settings-time-' . $user_id, time(), time() + YEAR_IN_SECONDS, SITECOOKIEPATH, null, $secure );
    $_COOKIE['wp-settings-' . $user_id] = $settings;
}
```

I thought I was on the right track with this part, and maybe I am, but it does not have the desired end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up adding to my plugin, and users report that it has been successful:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', array( $this, 'after_successful_login' ), 10, 2 );
/**
 * Make sure the auth cookie is set when a user logs in
 *
 * @param  string  $login   The user's username
 * @param  object  $user    The logged in user object
 *
 */
public function after_successful_login( $login, $user = '' ) {
    if ( ! ( $user instanceof WP_User ) ) {
        return;
    }
    /**
     * Log in a user by setting authentication cookies.
     *
     * @param  int   $user_id
     * @param  bool  $remember
     * @param  mixed $secure
     *
     */
    $remember = filter_var( get_option( $this->option_prefix . 'remember_user_login', false ), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, $remember, is_ssl() );
}
```

None of the replicating of `wp_user_settings` that I had tried above was necessary, just that.